# Did Mavericks change the Mac's color profiles?

Tags: color, macos

I just updated to Mavericks and noticed that the Skype icon in my dock is a deeper blue than it was before, and it looks like there's more contrast in general. Did the new version of OS X modify the color profiles?

I do web design work, so color accuracy is pretty important for me. I got used to the old colors, so this change might be problematic for me.

Did OS X change the color profiles? Is there a way to turn them back?

Comment: I know that this is probably silly, but I seriously want to know: what's the use of all this color profile uptightness for web design work? User's devices are all uncontrolled anyway, so whatever painstaking care one puts in presumably goes all to waste. Of course for print and generic work I fully understand the need.

Comment: It's not because my colors are perfectly calibrated or anything, or I want everything to look perfect everywhere (at least that's me). It's just that I've been working with certain colors for a year and them being changed makes it harder for me to recognize them and use them.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the standard profiles included with Mac OS X suggests two profiles have changed:

- Generic Gray Gamma 2.2 Profile.icc
- Generic Gray Profile.icc

## Profile md5 Signatures

The profiles were compared using a simple file content check using `md5`:

```
cd /System/Library/ColorSync/Profiles
md5 *
```

### OS X 10.8

```
MD5 (AdobeRGB1998.icc) = dea88382d899d5f6e573b432473ae138
MD5 (Generic CMYK Profile.icc) = 25352f2fbfee39fe64c943b6fb0c8c4e
MD5 (Generic Gray Gamma 2.2 Profile.icc) = ad1250d8b778217110effe8e3423a9fb
MD5 (Generic Gray Profile.icc) = 38b0f5b73c0e2eb5beca4d8deef9cde9
MD5 (Generic Lab Profile.icc) = f7d68a979692ff32180a87a4b6837a70
MD5 (Generic RGB Profile.icc) = 0d258bad36b64cebfb9e6826c3ed5037
MD5 (Generic XYZ Profile.icc) = aad1e8dbdf81721d9e983f0b0ffcb046
MD5 (sRGB Profile.icc) = 1d3fda2edb4a89ab60a23c5f7c7d81dd
```

### OS X 10.9

```
MD5 (AdobeRGB1998.icc) = dea88382d899d5f6e573b432473ae138
MD5 (Generic CMYK Profile.icc) = 25352f2fbfee39fe64c943b6fb0c8c4e
MD5 (Generic Gray Gamma 2.2 Profile.icc) = 242a41879c1d88202a6863d14fa729b2
MD5 (Generic Gray Profile.icc) = 475ffd27e43ca94bd4bf997990076e0a
MD5 (Generic Lab Profile.icc) = f7d68a979692ff32180a87a4b6837a70
MD5 (Generic RGB Profile.icc) = 0d258bad36b64cebfb9e6826c3ed5037
MD5 (Generic XYZ Profile.icc) = aad1e8dbdf81721d9e983f0b0ffcb046
MD5 (sRGB Profile.icc) = 1d3fda2edb4a89ab60a23c5f7c7d81dd
```

## ColorSync Utility

You can use the included ColorSync Utility to examine the ColorSync profile in use by your displays.

```
Applications > Utilities > ColorSync Utility.app
```

Using this utility you can compare profiles with your last OS X 10.8 back-up and, optionally, restore any custom profiles you created. Restore easy access to prior profile by placing them within the `/Library/ColorSync/Profiles` folder.

[image: ColorSync Utility.app]

Comment: Also, if you don't have administrator access, `~/Library/ColorSync/Profiles` works as well.

Answer (score 1):

Mine is absolutely different. Warm colors are very over-saturated. I am in design as well and it's a very frustrating 'update' from Apple.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. Unfortunately, you'll have to wait to post your feedback until you have a bit more activity under your belt.

Comment: This is an answer, not a comment. The question is whether color profiles changed. This user reports that yes, color profiles changed.

Answer (score 1):

My custom profiles were deleted and the system was reset to the default profile - you'll have to recalibrate your screen.

Answer (score 0):

Mine were reverted to a default, but my original profiles were there and listed in System Preferences -> Display -> Color.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Apple changed the color profile in Mavericks. You can see the difference immediately. The black is not black, it's more like dark brown.

There is one way to get best color accuracy. You have to you any display calibrate app like [SuperCal](http://www.bergdesign.com/supercal/).
I also do some web design and photo manipulation work and it's necessary that you calibrate the screen.